# Airflow: Why the Rendered Template and Log query is different?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am running a SQL query using Airflow DAG (GCP Composer). The task runs without any error. But, It runs a previous version of the query. Interestingly, the 'Task Instance Details' and 'Rendered Template' has the current and right version but the 'Log' file prints the previous version of the query.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Example:

```
**Sample Task in the dag:**

table_3 = BigQueryOperator(
        task_id='create_table_3',
        sql='/sql/table_three.sql',
        params=dict(
            project_id=pro_id,
            dataset_id=data_pipe
        ),
        destination_dataset_table=f'{data_pipe}.Table_three',
        use_legacy_sql=False,
        allow_large_results=True,
        write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE'
    )
```

Dummy Part of the rendered query

```
T3 AS (
    SELECT 
         DateTime
        ,NAME
        ,ID
        ,Input
        ,output
    FROM T2
    WHERE ID IS NOT NULL
)

,T3_intertable as (
SELECT 
     DateTime
    ,NAME
    ,Input AS Input_1
    ,output AS Output_1
FROM T3
order by DateTime
)
```

Dummy part of the Log query

```
[2020-12-15 05:23:40,689] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2663300: Subtask create_table_3 T3 AS (
[2020-12-15 05:23:40,689] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2663300: Subtask create_table_3  SELECT 
[2020-12-15 05:23:40,689] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2663300: Subtask create_table_3       DateTime_UTC
[2020-12-15 05:23:40,690] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2663300: Subtask create_table_3      ,NAME
[2020-12-15 05:23:40,690] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2663300: Subtask create_table_3      ,TRAIN
[2020-12-15 05:23:40,690] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2663300: Subtask create_table_3      ,ID
[2020-12-15 05:23:40,690] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2663300: Subtask create_table_3      ,Input
[2020-12-15 05:23:40,690] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2663300: Subtask create_table_3  FROM T2 
[2020-12-15 05:23:40,690] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2663300: Subtask create_table_3  WHERE ID IS NOT NULL 
[2020-12-15 05:23:40,691] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2663300: Subtask create_table_3 )
[2020-12-15 05:23:40,691] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2663300: Subtask create_table_3 SELECT 
[2020-12-15 05:23:40,691] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2663300: Subtask create_table_3   DateTime_UTC
[2020-12-15 05:23:40,692] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2663300: Subtask create_table_3  ,NAME
[2020-12-15 05:23:40,692] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2663300: Subtask create_table_3  ,TRAIN
[2020-12-15 05:23:40,692] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2663300: Subtask create_table_3  ,Input AS Input_1  
[2020-12-15 05:23:40,692] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2663300: Subtask create_table_3 FROM T3
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved. This might be an airflow glitch. I basically replaced (without deleting) the updated query with the previous one. Now, I deleted the previous query file and upload the new (updated) query in sql folder in the DAG.

This fixed the problem.